# Loop through SQL Server Select staement results and use them for another SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, loops, select

I am trying to run a basic select statement to return a list of job numbers. I want to then take that list of job numbers and crank them through 4 different select statement to see if I get any results. The point of this is to create a watchdog list to notify me if any parts from any jobs have not been created. Here is my code thus far:

```
 --Search for all Jobs
--Use select statement here to return a list of job numbers


--Then crank through both of the following queries to see if I get any results
--Laser 1
SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.table1
WHERE PARTNAME NOT IN (SELECT PARTNAME FROM db2.Laser1.dbo.Part WHERE ORDERNO = @JobNumber)
AND DISTRICT = 1 AND ORDERNO = @JobNumber

--Laser 2
SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.table1
WHERE PARTNAME NOT IN (SELECT PARTNAME FROM db2.Laser2.dbo.Part WHERE ORDERNO = @JobNumber)
AND DISTRICT = 3 AND ORDERNO = @JobNumber
```

In short I want to use a select statement to return all jobs that are currently in proccess. Then replace the @JobNumber with that job and see if it returns anything.

Comment: If I were you, I'd select the job numbers into a #temp table and change your `ORDERNO = @JobNumber` into an `ORDERNO in (select jobnumber from #temp)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.  (just the critical components)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sparse on details here but you definitely don't need a cursor or a loop for this. Something like this perhaps?

```
select *
from Jobs j
where j.PARTNAME not in
(
    SELECT p1.PARTNAME 
    from db1.dbo.table1
    left join db2.Laser1.dbo.Part p1 on p1.ORDERNO = @JobNumber AND DISTRICT = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p2.PARTNAME 
    from db1.dbo.table1
    left join db2.Laser2.dbo.Part p2 on p2.ORDERNO = @JobNumber AND DISTRICT = 3
)
```